# genvar is missing for generate "loop" variable : verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

Getting error `9: error: genvar is missing for generate "loop" variable 'r'.
1 error(s) during elaboration.`

The entire code:

```
module divider (dividend, divisor, quotient, remainder ) ;
    input [7:0] dividend ; // eight input lines modeled as a bus
    input [7:0] divisor ; // select lines bundled as a bus
    output reg [7:0] quotient ;
    output reg [7:0] remainder ;
    reg [7:0] r;
    reg [7:0] q;
    assign q = 0;
    for(r = dividend; r >= divisor; r = r - divisor)
        assign q = q + 1;
    assign remainder = r;
    assign quotient = q;
endmodule

module main;
    reg [7:0] dd;
    assign dd = 12;
    reg [7:0] dr;
    assign dr = 5;
    reg [7:0] q;
    reg [7:0] r;
    wire a = divider(dd, dr, q, r);
    initial begin
    $display("quotient %d", q);
    $display("remainder %d",r);
    end
endmodule
```

I'm trying to write a module to calculate quotient and remainder by repeated subtraction using behavioral modeling in verilog. This is my first verilog program and I'm having trouble fixing these errors, please point out if there are any other errors in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the for loop. You can either use **generate** block or **always** block to use it. One of the way to do is as follows :

```
module divider (dividend, divisor,quotient, remainder ) ;
input [7:0] dividend ; // eight input lines modeled as a bus
input [7:0] divisor ; // select lines bundled as a bus

output reg [7:0] quotient ;
output reg[7:0] remainder ;

 always @(*) 
  begin
       quotient=0;
       for(remainder = dividend; remainder >= divisor; remainder = remainder - divisor)
          quotient = quotient + 1;            
  end

endmodule



module main;

reg[7:0] dd; 
reg[7:0] dr;

wire [7:0] q;
wire [7:0] r;

divider d0( .dividend(dd), .divisor(dr), .quotient(q), .remainder(r) ) ;

initial begin
   dd=12;
   dr=5;
end

initial begin
 #20  $display("quotient %d", q);
 #25    $display("remainder %d",r);
end

endmodule
```

Few things to note:

1. If you wan to assign a variable using **assign** statement, declare that variable as **wire**.
2. In the testbench, you need to define inputs as "reg" and outputs as "wire".
3. You cannot use **assign** in for loop.

Comment: The code you provided for the divider logic will not work as intended as you use NBA in the loop. This means that it will NOT update `quotient` on each loop, but instead only result in `quotient` being set to 0 or incremented from its previous value, which in your case was from the previous attempt to divide. Also, you use blocking assignment for `remainder` in a clocked `always` block, which result in simulations that do not properly simulate real hardware.

Comment: @Unn I found my mistake :) . Will it be a problem at the hardware level if I use all blocking assignments in always block? Because it works fine at the simulation level if I convert NBA to blocking assignments  .

Comment: While this setup might appear to be working fine with blocking assignment, as soon as you integrate it into a design that uses `quotient` or `remainder` in some other module or block, simulation will have a race condition. To accurately simulate hardware, you need to use NBA in clocked blocks (and BA in combinational blocks like `always @(*)`). Synthesis tools usually can figure it out if you use BA; but you should never use BA in clocked blocks.